# Find out, if managed property is user generated or created by SharePoint via Powershell

Tags: powershell, managed-property, default-value

We have a solution where several developers (from different companies) are working on the system and need to create a deployment solution. Now we finally have naming conventions (thank god), but at the beginning it was a little bit chaotic so the Managed Properties are kind of screwed up.

Is there a way to find out, if a managed property is user generated or created by SharePoint via PowerShell?